# How to run a python script from a c# client at a specific place

Tags: python, c#, .net, powershell

I wrote a little C# tool to parse data from textfiles to fit a specific format.
On the other hand I have a python script to draw graphs from the data.

After parsing the data I run the python script, which saves the graphs as PNGs.

In powershell I use just two commands:

```
cd C:\Users\name\Desktop
python .\MyScript.py
```

Is there a possibilty to automate this? To run the script "MyScript.py" at a specific place triggered from my C#-Tool?

Something like:

```
// open powershell
...

// run cd C:\Users\name\Desktop and python .\MyScript.py
...
```

Comment: via IronPython?

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/1679220).  You run CMD and pass the arguments.